# Excel VBA - importing data from another workbook in different directory via sql query (No Open.file method)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, import, worksheet

I am not able to gather data from an external workbook and copy it. I can do it in the same workbook; but I cannot write down the path or something missing. The problem may be related with the `shRead()`.

```
Sub ReadFromWorksheetADO()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim sourceFile, wFile As String
Dim shRead, shWrite As Worksheet

Set shWrite = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("D2")
sourceFile = "\\X\Y\Z\3_6\deneme6.xlsm"

connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='\\X\Y\Z\3_6\deneme6.xlsm';" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"

' Not sure need this definition -> wFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "CurrentWB.xlsm"'

shRead = "[Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & sourceFile & "]"

Dim query As String
query = "Select * from [" & shRead.Name & "$] Where Item='1' "
'Alternative one -> query = "Select * from [R3.6$] Where Item='1' "'

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open query, connection

shWrite.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
connection.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim shRead, shWrite As Worksheet only dims shWrite as a worksheet. ShRead is defined as a variant. So when you write shRead = "[Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & sourceFile & "]" that sets shread to a string. And a string doesn't have properties in VBA so shRead.Name is null

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to improve the code with the correction you mentioned. shRead is defined as Var/String right now and get rid off .Name end. I do not know if database defn  line takes worksheets as well as workbooks. That'swhy I tried to add [wsRead = "Application.Worksheets(1)"] as worksheet that I am working on. And attached it in query as [query = "Select * from [" & dsh & "].[" & wsRead & "] Where Item='1' "]. Still I get a Runtime Automatization error. Am I at the correct path, it seems a bit tangled since I work with this connections for the 1st time. BR.

Comment: SOLVED! It was a real pain for 2 weeks for me because the problem was related with the data type mismatch at query definition; however the "Run-time error -2147217913 (80040e07) Automation error"  was at line: rs.Open query, connection, and totally meaningless. Besides not enough information  was available with this error. The problem was related with my data type where '1' was not numerical in my source file. I replaced '=' with 'LIKE' and code run smoothly.   I also deleted line: shRead = "[Excel 12...", which was totally unnecessary for my connection. Hope this helps other frustrated souls.